# Count on multiple left joins on same table in one query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

SQL experts, I have a table of staff phone numbers and a table of every call that came in to our organisation over a year and need to count for each phone number the number of calls made and received.

Table **PhoneNumbers**:

| PhoneNumber | UserName | EMailAddress |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02078821122 | JBloggs | jbloggs@myorg.com |

Table **Calls**:

| Date | CallSource | CallDestination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/10/2020 | 07805424828 | 02078821122 |

So my T-SQL script is as below, as I need to do a left join on the Calls table twice, as the staff PhoneNumber may be either the source or destination of the call:

```
SELECT P.PhoneNumber, count(CS.CallSource) AS CallsMade, count(CD.CallDestination) AS CallsReceived
FROM PhoneNumbers P
LEFT JOIN Calls CS ON P.PhoneNumber = CS.CallSource 
LEFT JOIN Calls CD ON P.PhoneNumber = CD.CallDestination 
GROUP BY P.PhoneNumber
ORDER BY PhoneNumber
```

I do need the zero counts as well, hence the LEFT JOIN.  Although the script runs, the GROUP BY is causing the total CallsMade to be multiplied by the CallsReceived values for each PhoneNumber and the result is put in both columns.  So for example, say the PhoneNumber 02078820011 made 3 calls and received 2 calls, the above script is returning:

| PhoneNumber | CallsMade | CallsReceived |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02078820011 | 6 | 6 |

When it should be:

| PhoneNumber | CallsMade | CallsReceived |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02078820011 | 3 | 2 |

Can anyone advise how my script should be modified to get the correct counts?

Comment: First GROUP BY in subqueries, then JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unpivot the calls and aggregate:

```
SELECT v.PhoneNumber, SUM(source) as num_source,
       SUM(destination) as num_destination
FROM Calls c CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (c.CallSource, 1, 0), (c.CallDestination, 0, 1)
     ) v(PhoneNumber, source, destination)
GROUP BY v.PhoneNumber
ORDER BY v.PhoneNumber;
```

If you only care about numbers in the `PhoneNumbers` list, you can use:

```
SELECT p.PhoneNumber, SUM(source) as num_source,
       SUM(destination) as num_destination
FROM PhoneNumbers p LEFT JOIN
     (Calls c CROSS APPLY
      (VALUES (c.CallSource, 1, 0), (c.CallDestination, 0, 1)
      ) v(PhoneNumber, source, destination)
     )
     ON p.PhoneNumber = v.PhoneNumber
GROUP BY p.PhoneNumber
ORDER BY p.PhoneNumber;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, you assisted me twice now very helpful of you.  I presume I could group this by selecting the year and month in the way you demonstrated on my other question on counting customer orders?

Comment: @RashedHuq . . . Yes, you could aggregate this by additional keys.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a single `cross join` combined with two `case` tests:

```
select p.number, sum(case c.source when p.number then 1 else 0 end) sent, sum(case c.destination when p.number then 1 else 0 end) recieved
from phone p
cross join calls c
group by p.number
```

Comment: Thanks StringBuilder this script also worked perfectly well.